# Undefined symbol when migrating to Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgis, postgresql-11

After upgrading Postgres 10 to version 11, by using `pg_upgrade`, I get this error:

> could not load library "$libdir/postgis-2.4": ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so": /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined symbol: geod_polygon_init

I'm using CentOS 7 and Postgis 2.4.

I've tried to investigate a little.

```
# nm -D /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so |grep geod_polygon_init
  U geod_polygon_init
```

The function is exported by the shared library!
Why am I getting this error?

```
# ld -v /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so
GNU ld version 2.27-28.base.el7_5.1
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `repalloc'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `hash_create'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `get_guc_variables'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `init_MultiFuncCall'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `SPI_exec'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `WinGetFuncArgInPartition'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `SPI_gettype'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `geod_polygon_addpoint'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `get_fn_expr_argtype'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `GetDatabaseEncoding'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `SPI_execute'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `CurrentMemoryContext'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `SPI_getvalue'
...
```

Related questions:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1267282/could-not-load-postgis-2-4-so-undefined-symbol-float8getdatum
- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20180123173450.GK25452%40telsasoft.com

Comment: Why aren't you running PostGIS 2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded Postgis source code 2.4.5 and compiled it myself and now it works ok.

My `postgis-2.4.so` is much bigger than the provided by `yum`, 2.4 Mb vs 750 Mb.  The same can be said from other generated libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```
# ld -v /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so
GNU ld version 2.27-28.base.el7_5.1
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `repalloc'
/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined reference to `hash_create'
```

That's not actually a problem. You can't use ld like that, I think you want to use `ldd` there. It's a shared object, not a executable. Without a `_start` (or an entry point with `-e`) you can't call `ld` and produce an executable

> could not load library "$libdir/postgis-2.4": ERROR: could not load library "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so": /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-2.4.so: undefined symbol: geod_polygon_init

That error is because I believe you're linking against a version of Proj4 that is too old. That's a distro problem if anything.

Comment: `ld` tells me that `geod_polygon_init` is included in the `.so`.  This is what it interests me most.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @david.perez where does it do that, that's not anywhere in the question.

Comment: That;s true, I've clipped the output of the `ld` command because it was too long.  `nm` command also shows it is exported.  But the important point is that it works if I compile it myself.